# I shrank my font too small, How do I fix this?

Tags: gnome, fonts

I was trying to find the perfect font size and shrank the font to zero. now all the fonts in apps and menus are so tiny the dont even show with zoom. How can I fix this? Ubuntu 12.04 Gnome. I tried tabbing through advanced settings hitting ctrl&+ and managed to change window fonts. Too bad they are exactly where I want them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> keyboard shortcut and copy paste this command below and hit enter to execute it:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name 'Ubuntu 11'
```

Comment: Terminal responds with gsetting: command not found

Comment: It is `gsettings` not `gsetting`

Comment: i copied directly from your post and drug it to terminal.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: for whatever reason i had to use manual input. that got it. much thanks.

Comment: ubuntu 12.04. not a whole lot of experience with it but not ignorant of terminal. while youre still here, my terminal letters are all crammed up regardless of what font i use. whats up with that?

Comment: Please ask a separate question regarding the new problem. and if you think, the answer solves your original problem, you can accept it by clicking on the gray icon next to the answer. this will help future visitor